# Custom button user control style overwritten when content is set

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, user-controls

I am currently using Blend and some tutorials I found online to try to make my own button user control. Normally, I would just use a custom style and apply it to the controls I want, but I wrote in some dependency properties as well so I decided to write my own user control.

Something that I can't get my head around is how to set the Content property without overwriting the styling of the button control. I thought it might have been my code, but I started brand new with another button and I have the same thing happen - when the Content property is set, the button simply turns white and has black text in the upper left corner.

Here is the XAML code that Blend generated for me:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUI.Controls.MyButton"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="25" d:DesignWidth="100">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle/>
                        <ContentPresenter 
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                        RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="25" Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}" Width="100"/>
</Grid>
```

Now, if I reference the button in my main window like this, it reverts any styling that was done within the user control:

```
<local:MyButton Content="test" />
```

What do I need to change in order to make the button accept a different Content tag?

Comment: Did you create Content dependency property in your UserControl? If not, you are assigning "test" to UserControl's Content property, which original is Grid.

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure what you mean by creating the dependency property... I went ahead and added in: DependencyProperty ContentProperty but that doesn't have any affect on the button text (It keeps the style now but doesnt show the text at all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to connect your UserControl level Content property to your Button level Content property. By default UserControl's Content property is its only child element, which is Grid in your case. You can either create your own Content property or another one with different name. In your UserControl's .cs file:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MyButton.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MyButton : UserControl
{
    public new static DependencyProperty ContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof (object),
                                    typeof (MyButton));

    public new object Content
    {
        get { return GetValue(ContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
    }

    public MyButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

On your UnserControl's Xaml:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
            Height="25" Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}" Width="100"/>
```

Now Button's Content binds to your UserControl level Content property.

Comment: Hey - this is perfect minus one thing... Now, on my designer view I get the error: "Specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first.". I know it has to do with setting the Content property but I'm not sure how to get around that. Any ideas?

Comment: Modify code on XAML {x:Type UserControl} to {x:Type local:MyButton}, since you break the inheritance, you need let designer know you are using the Content from your specific UserControl.